# I have two type definitions, how can I determine if one is a base type of the other?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, reflection

I have two type definitions (references of type Class) in ActionScript 3 and I need to figure out if one is a base type (class or interface) of the other.

I had hoped something like the following would work, but alas it did not:

```
var isBaseClass:Boolean = MouseEvent is Event;
```

It is understandable why it doesn't, but it would still be nice. I can't use describeType either, since for objects of type Class it doesn't actually return the correct inheritance chain but rather just return the types Class and Object, which doesn't help at all. I *can* use getQualifiedSuperClassName in a loop until either there are no more super classes or there is a match, but it's less than ideal and doesn't work for type checking against interfaces.

Anyone have a better idea?

Comment: What is your pb with describeType ? What does it return ?

Comment: It doesn't return the inheritance chain of the class when you use it with type definitions, instead it returns the inheritance chain of the type reference, i.e. Class and Object. It is correct, but useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a live example using describeType with no problem : http://wonderfl.net/c/h90R

```
trace(describeType(MouseEvent)..extendsClass)
```

output :

```
<extendsClass type="Class"/>
<extendsClass type="Object"/>
<extendsClass type="flash.events::Event"/>
<extendsClass type="Object"/>
```

Comment: You are indeed correct sir, and it is because I only checked the immediate extendsClass and implementsInterface nodes. Using the descendants operator (..) as per your example will give you the inheritance chain of not only the type itself but also any instances of that type, it's just wrapped in the factory tag, which I had missed. Thanks for helping me spot this!

Answer (score 1):

I saw this suggested somewhere but haven't really tried it myself in practice:

```
var classA:Class = Event;
var classB:Class = MouseEvent;

trace(classA.prototype.isPrototypeOf(classB.prototype));
```

Comment: I assume this doesn't work with statically typed objects, but I'll give it a shot anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var classA:Class = Event;
var classB:Class = MouseEvent;

trace(classA.prototype.isPrototypeOf(classB.prototype));
```

As answered by Lars, this works for me. Make sure the base class is first (`classA`). `isPrototypeOf` is analogous to `isSuperClassOf`.